# How to receive the AsyncStorage items in FlatList?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

What I want to do is show the items saved in AsyncStorage in a FlatList.

```
savePosts = async () => {
try {
    let post = {
        postId: '1',
        postTitle: 'This is an example',
    }
    const posts = await AsyncStorage.getItem('posts') || '[]';
    posts = JSON.parse(posts);
    posts.push(post);
    AsyncStorage.setItem('posts', JSON.stringify(posts)).then(() => {
    });
} catch(error) {
}
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use state and initialise it in `componentDidMount`:

```
state = {
  data: [],
}

componentDidMount() {
  AsyncStorage.getItem('posts').then(data => this.setState({ data }));
}

<FlatList data={this.state.data} ...otherProps />
```

Alternatively, if you use Redux, you can call `AsyncStorage.getItem` anywhere and dispatch an action to populate the store, which the `FlatList` component can connect to and display the data.