# expecting newline or semicolon + unexpected token after function name

Tags: react-native

I have the following code:

```
export default class HomeScreen extends Component {

    state = {text: ''};

    _onPressSearch() {
        Alert.alert("Button pressed!")
    }

    function getCitiesListFromApiAsync() {
        return fetch("https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?lat=55.5&lon=37.5&cnt=10&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22.json")
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                return responseJson.list;
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                Alert.alert("Error while loading: " + error);
            })
    }

    render() {
        return (<View style={styles.container}>
            <ScrollView style={styles.scrollViewContainer} contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}>
                <View style={styles.searchContainer}>

                    <TextInput placeHolder="Type something!" onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
                               value={this.state.text}/>

                </View>

                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={this._onPressSearch}>
                    <View>

                        <Text>Search</Text>

                    </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>

                <View style={styles.container}>

                    <FlatList
                        data={this.getCitiesListFromApiAsync()}
                        renderItem={({item}) => <Text style={styles.item}>{item.name}</Text>}
                    />

                </View>

            </ScrollView>


        </View>);
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to get data from server, parse it and add it to flatlist. I get data from this API: https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?lat=55.5&lon=37.5&cnt=10&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22.json. I created a special function for it, the same as in [tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network). But my IDE (Webstorm) marks it in red and writes that there should be a newline or semicolon after `function` name and when I run the app I have the following error:

Failed building JavaScript bundle.
    SyntaxError: /Users/siarhei.mikhaylouski/WebstormProjects/WeatherApp/screens/HomeScreen.js: Unexpected token (23:13)

```
               function getCitiesListFromApiAsync() {
         |              ^
      24 |         return fetch("https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?lat=55.5&lon=37.5&cnt=10&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22.json")
      25 |             .then((response) => response.json())
      26 |             .then((responseJson) => {
```

What's the matter and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use the `function` keyword when you define a method inside a class.

Just write:

```js
getCitiesListFromApiAsync() {
  // [...]
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but now I have another problem: data isn't added to FlatList. I see nothing on the screen. Why does it happen?

Comment: `getCitiesListFromApiAsync` is asynchronous so the function does not return `responseJson.list` as you seem to think, it returns nothing and your flatlist has no data.
You should save the fetched data to your state and use the state in your flatlist. There are plenty of [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50243950/how-to-receive-the-asyncstorage-items-in-flatlist) of how to do this.